# The unbounded domains do not admit compact imbeddings into $L^P$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

The unbounded domains do not admit compact imbeddings $W^{1,p}$ to $L^p$

For this ..i consider an example

$\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ , let $I=(0,1)$ and $I_j=(j,j+1)$ for $j\in \mathbb{Z}$

Let $f\in C^1$ function compactly supported in $I$

define $f_j(x)=f(x-y),j\in \mathbb{Z}$

clearly $f_j\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $1\le p < \infty$ and the sequence $\{f_j\}$ bounded  in that space

now consider $|f_i-f_i|_{0,p,\mathbb{R}}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_i-f_j|^p\; dx$ from we here how to processed

**MY question**

how to prove this sequence cannot have  convergent subsequence

Comment: I guess you are talking about compact embedding into $L^p$ and want to show that the sequence has no convergent subsequence in $L^p$. If so, then you can just compute the $L^p$-norm of $f_j-f_k$.

Comment: @MaoWao..yes your right but im just little facing problem there

Comment: So just start: Write down the definition of the $L^p$-norm as an integral, split it into two parts, make the natural substitutions, and then tell us where exactly you're having problems.

Comment: @MaoWao here we want to find $|f_i-f_k|_{0,p,\mathbb{R}$ what u mean by split into two parts

Comment: As I said, write the $L^p$-norm of $f_j-f_k$ as an integral. The integrand is supported in $(j,j+1)\cup (k,k+1)$, which gives you the the two parts.

Comment: @MaoWao...$\int |f_i-f_j|^p=\int_(j,j+1) |f_i-f_k|^p +\int_(k,k+1) |f_i-f_k|^p$ u are saying disjoint supports how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104596/discussion-between-inverse-problem-and-maowao).